# Database column doesn't exist

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and am creating a small Twitter app for practice. I have the following models set up

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    #Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name="profile",
        verbose_name=_("user"),
        primary_key=True,
        )

    interaction = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name=_("interaction")
        )

    # Object Manager
    objects = managers.ProfileManager()

    #Custom Properties
    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username

    #Methods

    #Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Profile")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Profiles")
        ordering = ("user",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save,sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender,created,instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()

class Tweet(models.Model):

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile,unique=False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tweet")
        #ordering = ("profile","text")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Comment(models.Model):

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile,unique = False,default=None)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet,unique=False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

I would like the Comment Model to have to two Foreign keys: one to the User who posted it and one to the Tweet it is a comment of. Whenever I tried to run my app I get the following error:

```
column taskmanager_comment.profile_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "taskmanager_comment"."profile_id", "taskmanager_comm...
```

I have done `python manage.py makemigrations`. In addition,I have added a `default=None` to the profile foreign key in Comment because Django throws an error for a Non-nullable field if I don't add it. `python manage.py migrate` throws the following error every time I run it:

```
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 467, in alter_field
    old_field.rel.through._meta.auto_created and
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

which I am not sure if this error could be causing the previous error. Any ideas how to fix these errors?

Edit: Migrations:

```
 python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'taskmanager':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Comment
    - Create model MyModel
    - Create model Profile
    - Create model Tweet
    - Add field profile to comment
    - Add field tweet to comment
(tb_dev)lie@lie-bot:~/taskbuster_project$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: google, staticfiles, allauth, messages
  Apply all migrations: sessions, account, taskmanager, socialaccount, contenttypes, admin, auth, sites
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend removing the `primary_key=True' from your text fields. This makes them unique and indexed - meaning, no one will ever be able to tweet the same thing or comment the same thing. Also, primary keys are reserved for the id of that record, whether it is auto generated or generated by you.

Second, you do not need `unique=False` on your Foreign keys in the Comment model

Third, You do not need to associate the Comment model to the Profile model, since it is associated by the Tweet... Profile -> Tweet -> Comment

So:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # a field of 'id' is automatically generated for you as the primary key

    #Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name=_("user"),
        )

    interaction = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name=_("interaction")
        )

    # Object Manager
    objects = managers.ProfileManager()

    #Custom Properties
    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username

    #Methods

    #Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Profile")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Profiles")
        ordering = ("user",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save,sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender,created,instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()

class Tweet(models.Model):
    # a field of 'id' is automatically generated for you as the primary key

    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tweet")
        #ordering = ("profile","text")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Comment(models.Model):
    # a field of 'id' is automatically generated for you as the primary key
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile')
    tweet = models.ForeignKey('Tweet')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

is probably more of what you had in mind

Profile has a ONE-TO-ONE relationship to the AUTH_USER model. A Profile can have MANY tweets and a Tweet can have MANY comments.

To select someone's tweets and comments by username, you could call:

```
tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(profile__user__username='incognos').select_related('comments')
```

or by user record in a view:

```
tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(profile__user=request.user).select_related('comments')
```

This gets all the tweets by the user named 'incognos' and in the same query, selects all the related comments to that tweet.

I hope this helps and welcome to Python and Django....

Comment: Thank you. The reason I made text the primary-key is that if I let Django create the Auto update ID key, makemigrations would throw an error saying I can't add a Non-nullable field. In addition, Is there a way though to associate a comment with the Profile that produced it (i.e. Profile Timmy comments on a Tweet produced by Profile Sarah)? So all comments are not anonymous, or are you saying that is already handled through Tweet->Profile? That's what I was attempting to do with the Comment Foreign-key to Profile. Lastly, does that error from migrate mean anything?

Comment: I modified the comment model to allow for a profile association. The reason you are getting non-nullable field errors is probably because you ran the migration and created the tables, then added new fields, ran new migration, but those fields did not have default values. Unless you have pre-existing and important data, I would wipe out all the migrations and the tables and run the migration from scratch.

Comment: Thank you. I cleared the migrations and that fixed all the migration errors. However, I am now getting the error that the columns for the id field's for Tweet and Comment do not exist.

Comment: did the migration create the tables? can you look at your db structure and see if the id field exists? what db are you using? also, where and when are the erros occurring? traceback?

Comment: I am using postgresql. I tried  recreating the db and it ended up working. Thank you.

Comment: my pleasure... accept my answer if it ends up being the right one... cheers,